# Add-In not enabled after restart in Outlook 2010

Tags: outlook-addin

I would appreciate any help as I have exhausted every solution I found at this point.

The Load Behavior of an Outlook Add-In is listed as "**Unloaded**" under *File > Options > Add-Ins > COM Add-ins*. It will load and work as expected if I manually check the add in. However it automatically disables when Outlook is restarted. I cannot find a way to make this stick.  The following is what I have tried based on Google searches:

1. The registry shows that all available **LoadBehavior** options are set to 3, which indicates that it should load automatically. For good measure I searched for every occurrence of "LoadBehavior" to see if I was missing anything, but they are all set to 3.
2. The "**Resiliency**" options in the registry called "**CrashingAddinList**" and "**DisabledItems**" are empty, indicating that this add-in is not being forced to disable. Again I searched for every occurrence of this in the registry and they look good.
3. I added a "**DoNotDisableAddinList**" entry into the **resiliency** in the registry and gave it a value of 1. This is supposed to load the add-in no matter what.
4. I uninstalled the add-in, cleared out any reference to it in the registry, rebooted, and reinstalled. The same issue continues.

If I set the user as an administrator on their desktop, the add-in is loaded automatically in Outlook and works as expected. This is the ***only*** time it works, however nobody else has this issue and they are not set as administrators on the desktop.

Any ideas?

Thanks
Ian

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your add-in fires an exception at startup...

Microsoft Office applications can disable VSTO Add-ins that behave unexpectedly. If an application does not load your VSTO Add-in, the application might have hard disabled or soft disabled your VSTO Add-in.

Hard disabling can occur when a VSTO Add-in causes the application to close unexpectedly. It might also occur on your development computer if you stop the debugger while the Startup event handler in your VSTO Add-in is executing.

Hard disabled add-ins are listed under the `DisabledItems` windows registry key.

Soft disabling can occur when a VSTO Add-in produces an error that does not cause the application to unexpectedly close. For example, an application might soft disable a VSTO Add-in if it throws an unhandled exception while the Startup event handler is executing.

When you re-enable a soft-disabled VSTO Add-in, the application immediately attempts to load the VSTO Add-in. If the problem that initially caused the application to soft disable the VSTO Add-in has not been fixed, the application will soft disable the VSTO Add-in again. See [How to: Re-enable a VSTO Add-in that has been disabled](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/how-to-re-enable-a-vsto-add-in-that-has-been-disabled?view=vs-2017) for more information.